# Суммирование по чекбоксу

Tags: javascript

Добрый день.
Собственно вопрос такой, на странице есть 3 формы. 2 с радио кнопками, одна с чекбоксами, и в зависимости от выбранных пунктов изменяется итоговая цена. С радио кнопками всё в порядке, а с чекбоксом 1 раз прибавляется нормальное значение, потом вычитается это значение  2, и прибавляется снова умноженное 2.

```
var a = 0,
    b = 0,
    c = 0;

//проверяем первую форму
function checkForm1() {
    var firstBlock = document.getElementsByName("firstStep");
    var summ1;
    var here = 1;

    for (var i = 0; i < firstBlock.length; i++) {
        if (firstBlock[i].checked) {
            a = 0;
            if (i == 0) {
                summ1 = 55;
                updatePrice(summ1, here);
            } else if (i == 1) {
                summ1 = 3;
                updatePrice(summ1, here);
            } else if (i == 2) {
                summ1 = 4;
                updatePrice(summ1, here);
            } else if (i == 3) {
                summ1 = 45;
                updatePrice(summ1, here);
            }

        }
    }
}

//проверяем вторую форму
function checkForm2() {
    var secondBlock = document.getElementsByName("secondStep");
    var summ2;
    var here = 2;

    for (var i = 0; i < secondBlock.length; i++) {
        if (secondBlock[i].checked) {
            b = 0;
            if (i == 0) {
                summ2 = 10;
                updatePrice(summ2, here);
            } else if (i == 1) {
                summ2 = 33;
                updatePrice(summ2, here);
            } else if (i == 2) {
                summ2 = 34;
                updatePrice(summ2, here);
            }
        }
    }

}

//проверяем 3ю форму
function checkForm3(cb) {
    var here = 3;

    cb = document.getElementById("cb1");
    c = 0;
    if (cb == cb1) {
        if (cb.checked) {
            updatePrice(5, here);
        } else {
            updatePrice(-5, here);

        }
    }
}

//считаем и выводим результат.
function updatePrice(sum, whereCome) {

    var place = document.getElementById("cost");
    place.innerHTML = '';
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    if (whereCome == 1) {
        a = sum;
    }
    if (whereCome == 2) {
        b = sum;
    }
    if (whereCome == 3) {
        c = sum;
    }

    span.innerHTML = "<h1>Стоимость составит: " + (a + b + c) + "</h1>";
    place.appendChild(span);

}
```

подскажите пожалуйста как с этим бороться?

Comment: Вы принципиально не используете jQuery или другую вспомогательную библиотеку или такие требования? Используйте Array.prototype.forEach для перебора коллекций.

Comment: Да собственно с JQuery пока не знаком. Собственно что получается: складываем все первые значение 55+10 = 65. ставлю галку в чекбоксе, всё правильно 65+5=70. Убираю галку 70-5= ... 60. Снова ставлю 60+5=70...